# register page redirect to home page in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I have a register button for registration and route to register page in Laravel project. It works well, but now it redirects to home page. I clear the cache but does not work. Then I restart the project, now it works. 
What is the problem? How can I fix the problem for next time without restart?

Comment: After registration success you must be marking user logged-in and sending user to home page. Next time when you are visit registration page, Laravel checks if user is logged-in, if he/she is, laravel redirects to home page. Can you please confirm this?

Comment: If you use laravel `auth` then go to `RegisterController` and change `protected $redirectTo = '/home';` to what you want to link.

Comment: I have the same problem. Does you solve your problem?